# Não consigo atualizar meu objeto utilizando PUT

Tags: java, spring

Apesar de conhecer muito pouco o Spring porque estou aprendendo, não consigo salvar um objeto recuperado, o erro está quando passo o objeto **pessoaRepository.save(pessoaSalva)** cheguei até ver uns exemplos, mas achei dificil de entender devido ao pouco conhecimento que ainda tenho.

```
@PutMapping("/{codigo}")
public ResponseEntity<Optional<Pessoa>> atualizar(@PathVariable Long codigo, @RequestBody Pessoa pessoa) {
    Optional<Pessoa> pessoaSalva = pessoaRepository.findById(codigo);
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(pessoa, pessoaSalva, "codigo");
    pessoaRepository.save(pessoaSalva);
    
    return !pessoaSalva.isEmpty() ? ResponseEntity.ok(pessoaSalva) : ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Boa Noite @dayson rodrigues, seria correto vc possuir uma classe form ou simplesmente colocar a entidade no paramentro, o spring boot tem a capacidade de converter os dados vindos do HTML pro java, desde que eles possuam o mesmo nome e tipo, assim ele pode receber os dados com vc somente precisando chamar o método save() passando a entidade recebida pelo parametro, que normalmente o método deve fazer update caso o id não seja null e save caso o id seja null, vou deixar um link de um repositório, só dar uma olhadinha que irá facilitar as coisas ;)

O seu método ficaria assim:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/salvar", method=RequestMethod.POST)
//aqui já recebendo os campos com o mesmo nome dos atributos da entidade
public Pessoa salvar(Pessoa pessoa) { 
   if(pessoa != null){
    return pessoaRepository.save(pessoa);
   }
   return null;
}
```

https://github.com/rattherootkit/calendar

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que seja por não estar conferindo se o `Optional` está vazio ou não, por exemplo:

```java
Pessoa pessoaSalva = pessoaRepository.findById(codigo);
  if(pessoaSalva.isEmpty(){
   \\lançar uma exceção aqui
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, na hora do save você esta salvando o optional, o metodo save espera um Objeto, no caso se vocÊ usar um `.get()` no objeto resolve.

```
@PutMapping("/{codigo}")
public ResponseEntity<Optional<Pessoa>> atualizar(@PathVariable Long codigo, @RequestBody Pessoa pessoa) {
    Optional<Pessoa> pessoaSalva = pessoaRepository.findById(codigo);
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(pessoa, pessoaSalva, "codigo");
    **pessoaRepository.save(pessoaSalva.get());**
    
    return !pessoaSalva.isEmpty() ? ResponseEntity.ok(pessoaSalva) : ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).